# Как сделать обработчик ошибок от pyTelegramBotApi

Tags: python, telebot

Всем здравствуйте.
У telebot есть что-то вроде ?:

```
try:
    s = [1, 2]
    print(s[2])
except IndexError:
    print('error')
```

Только для своих ошибок.
Мне нужно как-то отреагировать есть в message.text есть HTML теги

Answer (score 0):

Если код будет вызываеть какое-либо исключение его можно словить и вывести его тип. А в дальнейшем ловить именно этот тип исключений.

```
try:
    1/0
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e)) # <class 'ZeroDivisionError'>
    print(e) # division by zero
```

Это работает т.к. все исключения наследуются от базового класса Exception.
Но если это кастомные исключения(из библиотеки допустим), то их надо подключать через import.