# Как сделать обработчик ошибок в aiogram боте?

Tags: python, json, aiogram

Ссылки на телеграмм каналы, в которые нужно сделать пост, берётся из json файла, их там много. Если хотя бы один канал вписан неправильно, весь бот ложится, мне нужно чтоб бот работал дальше .Подскажите, как в aiogram делают обработчик ошибок, сам в документации найти не смог.
Пример ошибки:
aiogram.utils.exceptions.ChatNotFound: Chat not found

Comment: A в документаций пайтон искали?

Comment: я знаю только try except, он конечно обрабатывает эту ошибку, но в except я не могу записать эту ошибку(ChatNotFound: Chat not found), думаю это как то через aiogram делается

Comment: except ChatNotFound: импортировать из aiogram.utils.exceptions или исползовать болле высокую по иерархии except Exception: будет обрабатовать все ошибки включая ChatNotFound кроме системных

Comment: Спасибо! Помогли

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1408044/470333